# Rails - Create and operate on a temporary table?

Tags: r, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My background is in data science with R, but in my current position I'm pulling data through Rails and ActiveRecord. I want to perform transformations to my data and create new columns and save it in a temporary way that allows me to continue querying it like a regular table, but without actually making changes to the database.

In R, this might look something like:

```
new_table <- old_table[old_table$date >= '2020-01-01']
new_table$average <- mean(new_table$value)
```

I would take this new_table and perform any number of queries I could have done to the old_table, and once I close my app I expect this temporary table to be removed as well.

This particular transformation is simple and wouldn't require a new table, but for example, there are a number of tables I'd like to join with my new_table. It would be easier if I could perform my transformations once and then join it, rather than joining the old_table and performing the transformation each time.

Comment: When you say it _would be easier_ what do you care about easier to write and maintain in source code? Or easier and more performant for the database engine?

Comment: Certainly easier for the source code. I assumed it would be easier for the database engine too as it seems less computationally intensive, since I only run the necessary transformations once. Is that not correct?

Comment: Depending on the DB server you're using, a materialized view may be what you're looking for. It is possible to create one in Postgres and MySql via some hacks

Comment: You could use views, and there are gems for that. But you could also just create temp tables in you DB directly either using one of the SQL methods or by accessing that system directly. Here is a good example... https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/using-temporary-tables-in-postgresql-with-rails/

Comment: It's unclear what you mean at the end by "each time" and "close the app". A traditional Rails app is a web app, and uses ActiveRecord for persistence. How are you using Rails in this instance? Are you describing work that you want to do across multiple different web page views to interact with the data? Or is this an operation you are doing from a console? Your question will be hard to answer without more detail.

Comment: @Beartech Sorry for the lack of clarity. In R I'm used to temporarily saving data and modifications in local memory. In my current position, I connect to a remote server through my terminal and prepare data to be sent to web apps like dashboards and reports. I'm trying to mimic the functionality of R temporarily saving tables to local memory. I assume there must be some "temporary server memory" if I'm saving data structures like hashes to variable names, but I'd like to do that with a whole table. When I said "close the app", it would be more appropriate to say "disconnect from the server"

Comment: So you are basically running from the console? i.e. `rails c`? Are you accessing a Rails app or are you writing a rails app? R is a language, like Ruby. Rails adds a lot of functionality but it's a framework. Do you want to manipulate the data using SQL? Your example doesn't really help those who don't know R. You really need to flesh out your question with more detailed examples of what you want to do with the data, how it gets sent to web apps, etc. it is far to vague. There are literally thousands of possible answers at this point. Did you look at the link I posted?

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is vague I'll give a general answer that might not fit your use but it's a best guess at this point. There are numerous ways to use the DB connection in Rails to query directly, as referenced in the link in my comments above. But as an experiment I wanted to see if this would work and it does, at least with a project that is using Postgres. I wanted it to be DB agnostic so I'm avoiding calling the DB connection directly...

First create a temporary class in the Rails console:

```
rails c
Loading development environment (Rails...

class MyTempTable < ActiveRecord::Base
end
=> nil
```

**EDIT:**
In addition to the method below, you can also do this to create the table:

```
MyTempTable.find_by_sql('create temp table temp_tables AS select...')
```

This will create the temp table directly from a query. You could then use a join statement if you wanted data from more than one table in the new temp table, and you can add any additional columns you want

**End Edit**

Now you have a class that will act like a table with the usual ActiveRecord methods. Rails now assumes there is a table in the DB called my_temp_tables (must be plural). You can then create a temp table (if your DBMS supports temp tables) like this:

```
MyTempTable.find_by_sql('create temp table my_temp_tables(col1, col2... ')
```

Now you have a temp table with the columns you want. You can then do SQL operations using

```
MyTempTable.find_by_sql('INSERT INTO my_temp_tables SELECT * FROM ....')
```

You can then treat MyTempTable like any other model in Rails. If you wanted all the columns from one table joined with some columns from another table you can create the temp table as above, you just have to create all the columns first (at least in Postgres, in MSSQL you can probably create the temp table inserting directly from a select => join statement). If you are new to Rails you can grab column names by doing this on existing tables:

```
some_columns = SomeTable.column_names
=> ["id", "name", "serial", "purchased", ...]
```

Now you have an array of the column names so you don't have to type all of them. You can list out the columns you want from the various tables, cut and past them into the `create temp table...` statement, then `INSERT` the joined data into `MyTempTable`

If you do much of this regularly you'll probably want to keep a listing of all your column names in an text file. You can also create Rake tasks that do all of this and save the data to some format, or send it off to where ever it is supposed to go. That way you can have it all in a file that you can just run and it will create the temp tables, do the work, and then when it closes out the temporary classes and tables go away.

You might want to investigate some Ruby Gems, there are probably existing gems that do some of what you want. But as a proof of concept this works. You could also spin up a local Rails app and use scripting to import the data you want into tables, then just flush and recreate it at will.

Any Rails gurus that know of a better way, please add an answer or edit this one. This is mostly a thought experiment for me since I wanted to see if it was possible.

If you want to create views that you can access later on you could use a gem like https://github.com/scenic-views/scenic

Or something like this might be of interest: https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_db

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're keen on the benefits of having some structure and tools available to work on the data, but don't want the data persisted in a db table.
Maybe use a model without a table like [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html).